# How to compile code for Android with jack compiler?

Tags: java, android

I'm making small app for Android, unfortunately my computer is to weak to run Android Studio thats why I must do everything from terminal.

And now I want to compile my project with this command:

```
java -jar $(ANDROID_HOME)/build-tools/23.0.3/jack.jar --classpath $(ANDROID_HOME)/platforms/android-23/android.jar --output-dex $(DEV_HOME)/obj --import-resource $(DEV_HOME)/res $(DEV_HOME)/src/ $(DEV_HOME)/gen
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR: src/com/bps/teutons/MainActivity.java:3: The import android cannot be resolved
```

Why jack can't find android.jar even if I add --classpath android.jar?

Comment: This tutorial may helps.http://czak.pl/2016/05/31/handbuilt-android-project.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying to compile you need to convert all JAR files from your project to special format compatible witch jack with this command:

```
java -jar $(ANDROID_HOME)/build-tools/23.0.3/jill.jar --output $(DEV_HOME)/lib/android.jar $(ANDROID_HOME)/platforms/android-23/android.jar
```

As stated in this tutorial http://czak.pl/2016/05/31/handbuilt-android-project.html this step is necessary only if you are using jack in version lower than 1.2-rc2.